# Python/ Pandas - Updating Data for a Group of Records

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to update some data, but the data I need to update is part of columns I need to use to select the unique records.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'subid':'123','grade':'K'},{'subid':'123','grade':'3rd'}, {'subid':'123','grade':'6th'}, {'subid':'456','grade':'1st'},{'subid':'456','grade':'3rd'},{'subid':'456','grade':'5th'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

I am trying to use str.replace

```
df['grade'][df['subid']== '456'].str.replace('3rd','4th')
```

I am getting the following, but can't get the df to update.

```
3  1st
4  4th
5  5th
Name: grade, dtype: object

df
  grade     subid
0   K       123
1   3rd     123
2   6th     123
3   1st     456
4   3rd     456
5   5th     456
```

Trying to get the following as the final df

```
  grade     subid
 0  K       123
 1  3rd     123
 2  6th     123
 3  1st     456
 4  4th     456
 5  5th     456
```

Are there better approaches to updating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
In [138]: df.loc[df['subid']== '456', 'grade'] = df.grade.replace({'3rd':'4th'})

In [139]: df
Out[139]:
  grade subid
0     K   123
1   3rd   123
2   6th   123
3   1st   456
4   4th   456
5   5th   456
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a more complex selection of rows and the assignment operator:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pandas as pd

data = [{'subid':'123','grade':'K'},{'subid':'123','grade':'3rd'}, {'subid':'123','grade':'6th'}, {'subid':'456','grade':'1st'},{'subid':'456','grade':'3rd'},{'subid':'456','grade':'5th'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print df

df['grade'][(df['subid']== '456') & (df['grade'] == '3rd')] = '4th'
print df
```

This prints out:

```
  grade subid
0     K   123
1   3rd   123
2   6th   123
3   1st   456
4   3rd   456
5   5th   456

[6 rows x 2 columns]
  grade subid
0     K   123
1   3rd   123
2   6th   123
3   1st   456
4   4th   456
5   5th   456

[6 rows x 2 columns]
```